# PHP pass values from php file to other class

Tags: php, mysql, class, private

I am using a config.php file for a simular something, im trying to put my mysql credentials in there to then use them in a different file, but it does not pass the values,

is there any1 that could help me find a solution.

code config.php:

```
/* Database credentials*/
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbName = 'xx';
$dbUsername = 'xx';
$dbWachtwoord = 'xx';
```

code dbconnect.php:

```
<?php include 'config.php';
class Database
{
    private $host;
    private $db_name;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    public $conn;

    public function dbConnection()
    {
        $this->host = $dbHost;
        $this->db_name = $dbName;
        $this->username = $dbUsername;
        $this->password = $dbWachtwoord;
        $this->conn = null;
        try
        {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception)
        {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

Class.user dbconnection:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
require_once('dbconnect.php');

class USER
{   

    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }
```

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Show us how you call dbConnection() method. Then someone can help you.

Comment: `$this->host = $GLOBALS['dbHost'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include 'config.php inside your class

```
 public function dbConnection()
    {
        include 'config.php';
        $this->host = $dbHost;
        $this->db_name = $dbName;
        $this->username = $dbUsername;
        $this->password = $dbWachtwoord;
        $this->conn = null;
        try
        {
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than thinking about it as *passing variables*, think about it as passing configuration. It is necessary for your Database class to be aware of those configuration options in order for it to be used. In other words: once you create an instance of class Database it should be configured and ready to use, just like any service would.
I strongly suggest you follow the rule of [injecting the configuration as a dependency](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/configuration-settings-are-a-dependency-that-should-be-injected).

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code :

**config.php**

```
<?php 
return [
    'dbHost' => 'localhost',
    'dbName' => 'xx',
    'dbUsername' => 'xx',
    'dbWachtwoord' => 'xx',
];
```

**user class**

```
class USER
{   

    private $conn;
    private $config;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->config = include "config.php";
        $database = new Database(this->config['dbHost'], $this->config['dbUsername'], $this->config['dbWachtwoord'], $this->config['dbName']);
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

**dbconnect.php**

```
public function dbConnection($dbHost, $dbName, $dbWachtwoord, $dbName)
{
    //....
}
```